# What is the purpose of skin-deep?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let me start by saying that I am new to React and even newer to TDD coding in JavaScript.  I am currently working on a React / Redux application where we are testing all of our components.  Our current test suite consists of Jasmine, Mocha, Chai, Karma, and skin-deep.  For some of our components we are using skin-deep (see below -- skin deep is )

```
  import sd from 'skin-deep';

  describe('testing-text-editor', () => {

  let tree;
  let instance;
  let vdom;
  let field;
  let fieldInput;
  let callbackFunction;

  beforeEach(() => {
    field = 'description';
    fieldInput = '<div>I am the description</div>';
    callbackFunction = () => console.log('foo');
    tree = sd.shallowRender(React.createElement(TextEditor, { id: field, initialValue: fieldInput, onSubmit: callbackFunction }));
    instance = tree.getMountedInstance();
    vdom = tree.getRenderOutput();
  });

  it('testing-render-description', function() {
    // some tests
  });
})
```

Whenever we use skin-deep we are using it on components where we also use shallowRender.  I was wondering if anyone has a good understanding of what skin-deep is really doing? I've been searching all morning for a good description of its functionality and purpose but am yet to find a satisfying answer.

EDIT: Moved some logic to the beforeEach to be more descriptive with my problem

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try taking it out to see what breaks?

Comment: yeah, it breaks on the vdom and instances inside of the tests.  After removing all of the references theree I am left with just about nothing.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is; doesn't https://github.com/glenjamin/skin-deep/blob/one-point-oh/README.md sum it up pretty well?

Comment: (This also seems relevant: http://willcodefor.beer/react-testing-with-shallow-rendering-and-skin-deep/)

Comment: The place where I am getting lost is why we need this tree with a shallow render.  The part that I was most confused on was why this tree was of use to us.  Someone just sent me this var tree = sd.shallowRender(<MyList />);
var buttonElement = tree.dive(['MyItem', 'MyButton']).  Which seems to expalin why the tree is necessary because it allows us to dive deeper into components than we would be able to without skin-deep

Comment: Not only deeper, but more-specifically, and w/ (AFAICT) recursive on-demand rendering.

Comment: Interesting!  Thanks for the help